# Конфликт дженерик метода

Tags: java, generics

Есть класс:

```
    static class Test<T> {

     T t;
    
     <P> P get(P p) {
       return p;  
     }
   }
```

Если его метод вызвать так, то все хороше:

```
        Test<String> test = new Test();
        int i = test.get(1);
```

А если убрать дженерик тип с класса, то возникает ошибка:

```
    Test test = new Test();
    int i = test.get(1);//error - java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int
```

Почему такое поведение? Как глобальный дженерик тип T связан с тем что в методе P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Как глобальный дженерик тип T связан с тем что в методе P?*

Тип T на уровне класса никак не связан с типом P, используемым в методе.

Однако, если класс, объявленный как обобщённый (дженерик), *не предоставляет* никакой информации о типе обобщения как в случае `Test test = new Test()`, такой класс "превращается" в "грязный" класс (raw type) ещё на этапе компиляции и ему будет соответствовать код:

```java
static class Test {

    Object t;
    
    Object get(Object p) {
        return p;  
    }
}
```

Соответственно, компилятор будет возмущаться при попытке присвоить числу объект `Object` в строке `int i = test.get(1);`, о чём, собственно, и сообщает ошибка: `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int`.
Если очень хочется скомпилировать этот шедевр *без указания типа в классе*, достаточно использовать кастинг:

```java
Test test = new Test();         // raw-type Test
int i = (Integer) test.get(1);  // test.get returns Object
```

Аналогичный пример в [ответе на основном SO: *Using no parameters disables generics entirely.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29944262/13279831)